# SQL Server Maintenance Plan Fails to Rebuild the Indexes

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

When I run a maintenance plan to reorganize and rebuild tables indexes, it fails.
Below the last two rows that displays the fail:

```
 Source: Reorganize Index      
 Executing query "ALTER INDEX [PK_xxTableName] O...".: 15% com...  
 The package execution fa...  
 The step failed.
```

What would be the cause?

Comment: log the maintenance plan to file, might give more details here than "..."

Comment: Could be lots of stuff. Corrupt index? Index that got dropped after the job started? Hard to know based on what you're provided.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I  have found the answer to this.

I removed the tick from "Compact Large Objects" option and just included the re-organize and re-build indexes tasks and it succeeded!!! Also I will log to text file for future failure details.

Comment: Are you running both rebuild and reorganize in the same maintenance plan?